# Put a span class in the shortened product title

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, title

I'm trying to put a span class in the result of the title to be returned, however, I can not succeed to detect the class.

This is the original code:

```
//Limitar el número de caracteres en la página de tienda en WooCommerce
function short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars( $title, $id ) {
  // Para las paginas de categorías
  if ( is_home() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || 
    is_cart() && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) { 
    // Si el título del producto es mayor a 30 caracteres
    if ( strlen( $title ) >= 35) { 
      // Acorta el título a 20 caracteres
      return substr( $title, 0, 34 ); 
    } else {
      // Pero si el título no es más largo de 30, pone el título completo
      return $title; 
    }
  } else {
    return $title;
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars', 10, 2 );
```

I'm trying to put the following span class:

```
<span class="title-tooltip">' . $title . '</span>'
```

This is the final result code, without success of detecting the classe:

```
//Limitar el número de caracteres en la página de tienda en WooCommerce
function short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars( $title, $id ) {
  // Para las paginas de categorías
  if ( is_home() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || 
    is_cart() && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) { 
    // Si el título del producto es mayor a 30 caracteres
    if ( strlen( $title ) >= 35) { 
      // Acorta el título a 20 caracteres
      return substr( '<span class="title-tooltip">' . $title . '</span>', 0, 34 ); 
    } else {
      // Acorta el título a 20 caracteres
      return $title;
    }
  } else {
    return $title;
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars', 10, 2 );
```

This is the result in the front-end:

https://image.ibb.co/nJ09sn/span_class_title.jpg

As you can see in the image, the span class is shown in the frontend, it is deir, the classe is not detected.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Some charitable soul that can help me? I have tried a thousand ways and nothing ... without success.

Comment: Would you please edit your question and provide the code that is actually outputting the title? Perhaps the output is being wrapped in an escape function...

Answer (score 0):

You're `substr()` on the span which will chop the closing span off. I think what you want is:

```
return '<span class="title-tooltip">' . substr( $title, 0, 34 ) . '</span>';
```

Comment: The problem is that it does not detect me that it is an html class.

I've put your code:
https://image.ibb.co/fTm2dS/span_class_title3.png

And in the front-end it goes like this:
https://image.ibb.co/m1P5yS/span_class_title2.png

Comment: It looks like another filter is running 'htmlspecialchars()` or similar on it after your code runs. Try a higher number priority on the filter.

Comment: I have already tried it, however, it still does not execute the span class tag.